# Add icon to a button

Tags: html, css

I want to style my HTML button with  a cart icon on the left, Like the one shown below. using css and html can someone provide an example?

[image]

Please see my existing code.

```
   .btn {
  background: #47b1c4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #47b1c4, #00708B);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #47b1c4, #00708B);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #47b1c4, #00708B);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #47b1c4, #00708B);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #47b1c4, #00708B);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10;
  -moz-border-radius: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #52c7de;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #52c7de, #3ea2b3);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #52c7de, #3ea2b3);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #52c7de, #3ea2b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #52c7de, #3ea2b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #52c7de, #3ea2b3);
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

<input name="Dialogue" onclick="isListEmpty()" style="color:#ffffff;" type="button" class ="btn" value="Add to cart"/>
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far

Comment: [CSS gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) the solution of your query.

Comment: you can use ::before element in button like https://jsfiddle.net/jgsf1wae/

Answer (score 2):

You could add a span before the link with a specific class like so:

```
<div><span class="icon"></span><a href="#">Add to cart</a></div>
```

Use css gradient to color your button background.

And then give that a specific width and a background image just like you are doing with the button itself.

```
.btn span.icon {
  background: url(imgs/icon.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work. If you want more customized use this [site](http://buttonoptimizer.com/) to generate

```css
.btn {
  height: 37px;
  width: 37px;
  background-image: url('http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_32.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay, How do i add text on the right or ldft now it shows below the image. <input name="btnApprove" onclick="AddToCart()" class ="btn" type="button" value="Add To Cart" />

Comment: Use the site  http://buttonoptimizer.com/ for generate same.